# How to track separate QR codes on the same website?

Tags: extensions, extension-request

What I am trying to do is this - different agents will be given flyers to hand out.  Each agent will have a different QR code.

Bob's flyers will go to `(URL)/qr-coupon&id=001`

Jim's flyers will go to `(URL)/qr-coupon&id=002`

Mary's flyers will go to `(URL)/qr-coupon&id=003`

In the simplest case, the URLs will all redirect to the same page, with the same coupon.  In a better case, each QR code would generate a different coupon (maybe the ID is in the coupon somewhere), so that we can track visits vs. coupons turned in.

This way, as people scan them, we can count the hits and know which flyers are getting scanned, which ones are not, and hopefully which ones are generating actual returns as they are turned in as coupons.

I guess we could set this up to be a stand-alone PHP page, and a redirect to a landing page inside Joomla, but I was hoping there was something available that made this all easy to set up and maintain from within Joomla itself.  Does anyone know of an extension that would handle something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Any SEF url extension would solve this problem, for example AceSEF. Each of your QR codes basically represents some sort of URL, you can see this as random url, say /abcdef

What you have to do is map /abcdef to /qr-coupon&id=001 on your site. In AceSEF, the url feature does this.

Comment: I think what he's looking for is something that will auto generate coupon codes based on the page the user hits. So the urls are only half the solution. I was going to suggest the url thing be even more simple and just use 3 stock menu items with nice aliases. They don't need to have the &id in there even. The trick is what is ON those pages once they're loaded.

Comment: Thank you, Brian - that's exactly what I meant.  I COULD make the pages by hand, and then the URLs, but having one extension that did it all (and created the QR code, too) would make life more simple.

Comment: So could you install an extension with user profiles and give them a sub folder in acesef. This would create a page for each agent that you add? (You have to add them somewhere?)